# How to Get Value from input fields in cart page to admin order details page?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In the cart page, I already created two text fields, but I'm unable to get the value that user input in that fields to admin order details page.

How can I get the values in order details page and I also want to save that details in the database.

Below is the code of my cart page

```
<?php

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>
    <section class="checkout_display">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form  action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() );?>" method="post">
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 inset">
                        <div class="checkout_title">get started</div>
                            <div class="first_form">

                        <!--Code which display text field one -->
                            <div class="form-group" >
                                <label>Instagram username</label>
                                <input type="text"  name="igusername" required>
                            </div>

                        <!--Code which display text field second -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="useremail" required>
                            </div>

                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

                            <?php
                            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                                $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                                    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                                    ?>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Your package</label>
                                <select disabled>
                                    <option> <?php  echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );?> For
                                        <span><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                                                ?>          
                                        </span>
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /> Yes! send me special promotion and discounts</div>

                            <div class="btn">
                                <input type="submit" value="next">
                            </a>
                            </div>

                            <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>

                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' ); ?>

                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' ); ?>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>
```

Code which display text field one and second are the text box from where i want to get value which user input and want to display and store them in admin order details page after completion of payment

Comment: Where is the related code that displays/save the fields in cart page? You should always provide your related code in your answer even if it doesn't work. Without that nobody can help you. Keep in mind that people can guess things by magic and also you should give some context…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec now can you please check it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following that will display your posted fields values to Woocommerce session. When order will be placed, it will saved that custom session data as custom order meta data and display it in admin orders:

```
// Save the posted data to Woocommerce session
add_filter( 'init', 'set_instagram_posted_data_to_wc_sessions', 10, 3 );
function set_instagram_posted_data_to_wc_sessions() {

    if ( ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) && isset($_POST['igusername']) && isset($_POST['useremail']) ) {
        // Enable Woocommerce sessions (if not done yet)
        if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
            WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
        }

        $session_data = []; // initializing

        if( isset($_POST['igusername']) && ! empty($_POST['igusername']) ) {
            // Add the dropdown value as custom cart item data
            $session_data['ig_username'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['igusername']);
        }

        if( isset($_POST['useremail']) && ! empty($_POST['useremail']) ) {
            // Add the dropdown value as custom cart item data
            $session_data['ig_useremail'] = sanitize_email($_POST['useremail']);
        }

        // Set the data to custom wc_sessions
        if( sizeof($session_data) > 0 ) {
            WC()->session->set('ig_data', $session_data);
        }
    }
}

// Save the session data as custom order meta data (post meta data)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'action_checkout_create_order_callback', 10, 2 );
function action_checkout_create_order_callback( $order, $data ) {
    if( $session_data = WC()->session->get('ig_data') ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_ig_username', wc_clean($session_data['ig_username']) );
        $order->update_meta_data( '_ig_useremail', wc_clean($session_data['ig_useremail']) );
        
        // remove the data from Woocommerce session
         WC()->session->__unset('ig_data'):
    }
}


// Display custom data in Admin orders, below the billing address
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_after_admin_order_billing_address', 10, 1 );
function display_after_admin_order_billing_address( $order ){
    $ig_username = $order->get_meta('_ig_username');
    $ig_useremail = $order->get_meta('_ig_useremail');

    if( ! empty($ig_username) || ! empty($ig_useremail) ) :

    echo '<div class="instagram-userdata">
        <h3>'.__('Instagram user data').'</h3>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-top:6px;">
            <tr><th align="left">'.__('Username').':&nbsp;</th><td>&nbsp;' . $ig_username . '</td></tr>
            <tr><th align="left">'.__('Email').':&nbsp;</th><td>&nbsp;' . $ig_useremail . '</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>';

    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works now.

---

If it doesn't work with sessions you can use the following that will add the post data to hidden fields in checkout page and will post that data again when order is submitted… Everything else is the same as above…

So you can try alternatvelly:

```
// Display the posted data values in checkout hidden fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'set_instagram_posted_data_in_hidden_field', 10, 3 );
function set_instagram_posted_data_in_hidden_field() {

    if ( isset($_REQUEST['igusername'])|| isset($_REQUEST['useremail']) ) {
        // Display hidden fields with the Instagram posted values
        ?><input type="hidden" name="ig_username" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['igusername']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="ig_useremail" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['useremail']; ?>"><?php
    }
}

// Save checkout hidden fields values as custom order meta data (post meta data)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'action_checkout_create_order_callback', 10, 2 );
function action_checkout_create_order_callback( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['ig_username']) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_ig_username', sanitize_text_field($_POST['ig_username']) );
    }
    if ( isset($_POST['ig_useremail']) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_ig_useremail', sanitize_email($session_data['ig_useremail']) );
    }
}


// Display custom data in Admin orders, below the billing address
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_after_admin_order_billing_address', 10, 1 );
function display_after_admin_order_billing_address( $order ){
    $ig_username = $order->get_meta('_ig_username');
    $ig_useremail = $order->get_meta('_ig_useremail');

    if( ! empty($ig_username) || ! empty($ig_useremail) ) :

    echo '<div class="instagram-userdata">
        <h3>'.__('Instagram user data').'</h3>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-top:6px;">
            <tr><th align="left">'.__('Username').':&nbsp;</th><td>&nbsp;' . $ig_username . '</td></tr>
            <tr><th align="left">'.__('Email').':&nbsp;</th><td>&nbsp;' . $ig_useremail . '</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>';

    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works now.

---

In Order pages in backend, you will get something like:

[image]

---

**To retrieve the data** from `$order` the `WC_Order` Object *(or `$order_id` the Order Id)* use:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // (optionally if required) with the Order ID

$ig_username  = $order->get_meta('_ig_username');
$ig_useremail = $order->get_meta('_ig_useremail');
```

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec thanks for your answer but the code is not working as it is not displaying anything under the billing section. I added the code in functions.php, and there is no single error in the code. But it is not showing data...  http://prntscr.com/nbqain

Comment: My fields are working fine I try $_POST['igusername']; code in checkout page and it is working fine.

Comment: @Ramansaab There was a little mistake… Try it again please. If it doesn't work I have another way too.

Comment: everything is good thanks for this code but last if statement for displaying data in admin orders not working because I tried it without if and it was working fine. can you please check it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use order meta to save anything to a particular order.

```
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 
    'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);
    function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) 
    {
       $order->update_meta_data( '_custom_text1', 'value' );
     $order->update_meta_data( '_custom_tex2', 'value' );
     }
```

Add your text box values to the value section of the meta key and they will store in the DB when the order is saved.

They will appear at the bottom of the order screen in admin section

Comment: Not working can you please give me full code? Currently, I'm using these names for input fields iguser, useremail.